# How to use Jquery Plugin with React js and react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router-dom, jquery-isotope

I am learning react js and trying to create a website with `react js` from a `Html template`. The template is using `Jquery Isotope image filter plugin` and my react code using `react-router-dom` for navigating page. when starting the app, in the `home page` the filter is working properly but when navigating to another page using the menu bar, the `isotope` filter does not work. It again works when i hard reload the page again. I have tried some way but that didn't work. So what is the way to use `Jquery Plugin` in a `react js` app ??

My Code is below:

`Index.html` page. Here i am declaring the `Scripts`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
    <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>

<body class="antialiased">
    <div id="root"></div>


    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/counterup/counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>

    <!-- Template Main JS File -->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

`Home.js` component. Here i am using the `isotope filter` plugin:

```
import React from 'react';'

export default function Home() {

    return (
        <>
            {/* <!-- ======= Portfolio Section ======= --> */}
            <section id="portfolio" className="portfolio" style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
                <div className="container" data-aos="fade-up">

                    <div className="section-title">
                        <h2>View Our Image Store</h2>
                        <p>Magnam dolores commodi suscipit. Necessitatibus eius consequatur ex aliquid fuga eum quidem. Sit sint consectetur velit. Quisquam quos quisquam cupiditate. Et nemo qui impedit suscipit alias ea.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
                        <div className="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <ul id="portfolio-flters">
                                <li data-filter="*" className="filter-active">All</li>
                                <li data-filter=".filter-app">App</li>
                                <li data-filter=".filter-card">Card</li>
                                <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">

                        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
                            <div className="portfolio-wrap">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" className="img-fluid" alt="portfolio-1" />
                                <div className="portfolio-info">
                                    <h4>App 1</h4>
                                    <p>App</p>
                                    <div className="portfolio-links">
                                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" data-gall="portfolioGallery" className="venobox" title="App 1"><i className="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                                        <a href="portfolio-details.html" title="More Details"><i className="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
                            <div className="portfolio-wrap">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" className="img-fluid" alt="portfolio-2" />
                                <div className="portfolio-info">
                                    <h4>Web 3</h4>
                                    <p>Web</p>
                                    <div className="portfolio-links">
                                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" data-gall="portfolioGallery" className="venobox" title="Web 3"><i className="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                                        <a href="portfolio-details.html" title="More Details"><i className="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
           </section>
```

And the `isotope plugin` is initialized in `main.js` script file that is integrated in the `index.html` page above.
So when i start the app, this page `Home` component works fine but when i go to another menu and come again to this menu then the `filter` doesn't work. What is the way to do this correctly?

Also i created below `hooks` to load the scripts in this `Home component` but doesn't work.
`Hooks` code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function loadScript(url) {

    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, [url]);
}
```

and called it from `Home` component like below:

```
import loadScript from '../hooks/loadScript'

export default function Home() {

    loadScript("assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/counterup/counterup.min.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js");
    loadScript("assets/vendor/aos/aos.js");
    loadScript("assets/js/main.js");
```

But is doesn't work. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may be having trouble loading jquery in. I would install it as an npm package:

```
npm i jquery
```

And then load jquery into your app like so:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

However, I'm not sure if it's failing for a different reason. You can load jquery as an npm package which might take some pain out of things, but I doubt that the jquery plugin you want to use exists as an npm package. I should mention that it is a little bit of an anti-pattern to use jquery within a React app. Not that you can't or shouldn't, but the challenge comes in trying to build a data model that is tracked within React's state management. When relying heavily on other libraries like jquery it can start to become a lot of work to stitch the two together.

That said, sometimes it still can be worth it to make use of a jquery plugin if it accomplishes something which cannot easily be done in a React plugin. You'll have to make the decision as to which is best in your case.

Comment: But all HTML template uses `Jquery plugins`. They do not use `react` when designing the templates. Then how can that templates be converted  to `react js` ?  There must be some way. Because maximum people uses `Html templates` to create websites. So let me know if there is any way.

Comment: I think you'll find that there's a lot of old content on the web for how to do things in jquery because that's how things used to be done. Now we have frameworks like React and Vue that provide a new way of building things, but if you don't follow the React paradigm you'll end up in a lot of pain. Again I'm not saying you can't use jquery but you need to know when to "say no" to jquery and do things the React way. I recommend walking through the tutorials on https://reactjs.org/ until you start to get a feel for how to build templates in React. You don't have to use jquery.